# Not sure if it's my query or if I need to add another table

Tags: mysql

What query can i run to get my articles to pull up along with my pages, will i need to add an intermediate table between articles and pages for me to get all the articles to show up under the specific page.

[image: this is what my articles table looks like]

[image: this what my pages table looks]

I would like for query results to match the article with the below page:

[image]

TABLES ARE AS FOLLOWS:

```
PAGES-
pages.pageId(INT),
pages.pageTitle(VARCHAR),

ARTICLES-
articles.acrticleId(INT),
articles.articleTitle(VARCHAR),
articles.pageId(INT),

VIDEOS-
videos.videoId(INT),
videos.videoTitle(VARCHAR),
videos.videoLoc(VARCHAR),
videos.articlesId(INT),

IMAGES-
images.imageId(INT),
images.imageTitle(VARCHAR),
images.imageLoc(VARCHAR),
images.articlesId(INT),

TEXT-
text.textId(INT),
text.text(medium),
text.articlesId(INT),
```

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT pageTitle,GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle)
FROM articles join pages using (pageId)
GROUP BY pageId;
```

Comment: #1146 - Table 'fonwv2.categories' doesn't exist

Comment: thanks it works changed category to pages and works like a charm

Comment: I thought the name of your table is categories. Updated the comment.